# How do I use QTextBlock?

Tags: c++, qt4, qtextedit

I'm completely new to C++ and Qt.

I want to populate a `QTextEdit` object with `QTextBlocks`, how do I do that?

*e.g.* If I have the sentence "the fish are coming" how would I put each word into its own `QTextBlock` and add that block to `QTextEdit`, or have I misunderstood how `QTextBlock` actually works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`QTextEdit` will let you add your contents via a `QString`:

```
QTextEdit myEdit("the fish are coming");
```

It also allows you to use a `QTextDocument`, which holds blocks of text.
The `QTextDocument` itself also can accept a `QString`:

```
QTextEdit myEdit;
QTextDocument* myDocument = new QTextDocument("the fish are coming", &myEdit);
myEdit.setDocument(myDocument);
```

However, "If you need to create a new text block, or modify the contents of a document while examining its contents, use the cursor-based interface provided by `QTextCursor` instead." [(Qt documentation)](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtextblock.html)  (Note, I added the `QTextBlockFormat` lines to make it explicit where the blocks are.)

```
QTextEdit myEdit;
QTextDocument* myDocument = new QTextDocument(&myEdit);
myEdit.setDocument(myDocument);
QTextCursor* myCursor = new QTextCursor(myDocument);

QTextBlockFormat format;
format.setBackground(Qt::red);
myCursor->setBlockFormat(format);

myCursor->insertText("the ");

format.setBackground(Qt::green);
myCursor->insertBlock(format);
myCursor->insertText("fish ");

format.setBackground(Qt::yellow);
myCursor->insertBlock(format);
myCursor->insertText("are ");

format.setBackground(Qt::red);
myCursor->insertBlock(format);
myCursor->insertText("coming!");

format.setBackground(Qt::green);
myCursor->insertBlock(format);
myCursor->insertText(QString(%1 blocks").arg(myDocument->blockCount()));
myEdit.show();
```

Seems like a lot of effort to go through to me.  Can you give any additional information on why you feel you need to use `QTextBlock`s?

Comment: I'm writing a program to help people to read another language (Greek) and each word has different grammatical information (such as "Verb, Indicative, Active, 3rd Person, Singular") which I would like to display when the mouse is moved over each word.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense then.  One problem with my example is that each block is displayed as its own line.  I don't have enough experience with `QTextBlock`s to know how to get them on the same line.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Keep them on the same line by using insertText without using insertBlock between.

For instance, when I tried

```
cursor.insertText("I will try ", textFormat);
cursor.insertText("this for you.", textFormat);
```

for you, the words all appeared on the same line.

insertBlock inserts a paragraph.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multiple QTextBlocks ? As I understand it, this creates multiple fragments in one QTextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/)

You could assign your string to a QString and then add that to the QTextEdit, or you could parse the QString using section() see [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qstring.html#section)