# How to get column number in qtextedit?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I can get the line number of a cursor in a QTextEdit. but can't achieve to get the column number information. (Note: I use QTextBlock while getting line number info.) Isn't there an easy way to obtain column number? What should i do? Although i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849558/how-do-i-use-qtextblock) and [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtextblock.html), QTextBlock class is still confusing me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution to the problem:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui.textEdit->textCursor();
int y = cursor.blockNumber() + 1;
int x = cursor.columnNumber() + 1;
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks (and shame on me for this easy question), but why the Qt people give a name such as blockNumber instead of line number and they insist using QTextBlock.