# pyqt: Get current line number of text cursor

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Is there a way to get the current line number of the text cursor in a QTextWidget? I can't see to find anything in the [documentation.](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html)

Comment: Take a look at the numberbarPaint function in a [blog post](http://john.nachtimwald.com/2009/08/19/better-qplaintextedit-with-line-numbers/). Apparently you can use the `textCursor`'s `position` method. See also [the position documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextcursor.html#position) for different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already answered at [How to get column number in qtextedit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942769/how-to-get-column-number-in-qtextedit)

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui.textEdit->textCursor();
int y = cursor.blockNumber() + 1;
int x = cursor.columnNumber() + 1;
```