# QPlainTextEdit ignores most of the text block formats

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qplaintextedit, qtextcursor

I wanted to increase spacing between paragraphs (text blocks) in QPlainTextEdit, to no avail. After experimenting I found that though some format properties (e.g., background color) take effect, others (e.g., margins) are ignored.

I found [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51891), but it mentions only `QTextBlockFormat::lineHeight()`. In my case, almost all methods of `QTextBlockFormat::*` are ignored. A minimal example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPlainTextEdit te;
    te.setPlainText("block1\nblock2\nblock3");

    QTextCursor cursor = te.textCursor();
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
    QTextBlockFormat fmt;
    fmt.setBackground(QColor(Qt::yellow));
    fmt.setBottomMargin(600);
    fmt.setIndent(20);
    fmt.setTopMargin(600);
    fmt.setLeftMargin(40);
    cursor.setBlockFormat(fmt);
    te.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Except `fmt.setBackground(QColor(Qt::yellow))`, others are all ignored. Using Qt 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `QPlainTextEdit` for intensive formatting over text. Use its cousin, **`QTextEdit`** instead.

Using your code and changing it from `QPlainTextEdit` to **`QTextEdit`** resolved the issue.

**FYI**, this was also mentioned in the [Bug Report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51891) you linked. Maybe you missed it or forgot to mention it in your question?

> Replacing QPlainTextEdit with QTextEdit shows the expected result.

```
QTextEdit te;               //  note the change in type
te.setPlainText("block1\nblock2\nblock3");

QTextCursor cursor = te.textCursor();
cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
QTextBlockFormat fmt;
fmt.setBackground(QColor(Qt::yellow));
fmt.setBottomMargin(6);     //  let's not overexaggerate anything
fmt.setIndent(1);
fmt.setTopMargin(12);
fmt.setLeftMargin(1);
cursor.setBlockFormat(fmt);
```

Here's the result of using `QPlainTextEdit` (on a MacOS).

[image: Oh no!!!]

And here's the result of using `QTextEdit` (on a MacOS).

[image: Yay!!!]

Note that none of the member functions need to be modified, so that's a plus. Transitioning from `QPlainTextEdit` to `QTextEdit` shouldn't be much of a pain.

**Further Reading**: [This other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849558/how-do-i-use-qtextblock) kinda helped. Would also be good to read if you're planning on using more Qt Text Classes.

Comment: Yes, I know that it works for QTextEdit :) For certain reasons, however, I am confined to deal with QPlainTextEdit. And so it looks not much as a bug, but as documented feature of a class (QPlainTextEdit) which in fact is merely not implemented....